# How does .Name work for variables?

Tags: powershell

```psh
param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=1)]
  [String]$fileName
)

#$fileName doesn't include the directory or the extension

$dir = "C:\Users\pb\Desktop\source"
$latest = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir |
          Where-Object {$_.Name -Like "*$fileName*"} |
          Sort-Object LastwriteTime -Descending |
          Select-Object -First 1 -exclude "*import*"

$fileName = $latest.name
$Source = "C:\Users\pb\Desktop\source\${fileName}"
```

Basically, does using the `.name` on `$latest` make `$latest` include the directory as well as the name or does it just include the name of the file,
e.g. does `$fileName` now equal `c:\users\pb\desktop\source\"fileName"` or just `"fileName"`?

Comment: Did you try the code to see what you get?

Comment: I have an IF statement to check to see if $Source is a valid path and its saying that it isn't a valid path so I know the problem is happening in the block of code i put above.

Comment: That's not an answer to my question. Output the value of `$filename` at that point and you will have your answer won't you? Also what is the test that is failing exactly?

Comment: the if statement was if ((Test-Path $Source) ). I went through and fixed it. It was in $fileName as you said. My list of testcases had a fileName that wasn't in the the data so it wasn't working correctly

Comment: *What* `if` statement? Show it to us. Also check the value of the variable and see what it is.

Comment: I appreciate your help. It was a user error and your advice of outputting the names of variables really helped me debug it too.

Answer (score 1):

In PowerShell, like many other languages, the dot-notation is used for accessing the properties of an object. In your case `$latest` contains a [`FileInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object (or a [`DirectoryInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object if `*$filename*` matches a folder), which has a number of properties, for instance `Name`, `FullName`, `LastWriteTime`, `Attributes`, etc.

You can display the properties of an object and their respective values by piping the object into the [`Format-List`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849957.aspx) cmdlet, while the type can be inspected for instance via the [`GetType()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method that each object has:

```
PS C:\> Get-Item 'C:\Temp\test.txt'
PS C:\> $f.GetType().FullName
System.IO.FileInfo
PS C:\> $f | Format-List *

PSPath            : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Temp\test.txt
PSParentPath      : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Temp
PSChildName       : test.txt
PSDrive           : C
PSProvider        : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem
PSIsContainer     : False
VersionInfo       : File:             C:\Temp\test.txt
                    InternalName:
                    OriginalFilename:
                    FileVersion:
                    FileDescription:
                    Product:
                    ProductVersion:
                    Debug:            False
                    Patched:          False
                    PreRelease:       False
                    PrivateBuild:     False
                    SpecialBuild:     False
                    Language:

BaseName          : test
Mode              : -a---
Name              : test.txt
Length            : 8
DirectoryName     : C:\Temp
Directory         : C:\Temp
IsReadOnly        : False
Exists            : True
FullName          : C:\Temp\test.txt
Extension         : .txt
CreationTime      : 03.06.2015 00:11:07
CreationTimeUtc   : 02.06.2015 22:11:07
LastAccessTime    : 03.06.2015 00:11:07
LastAccessTimeUtc : 02.06.2015 22:11:07
LastWriteTime     : 03.06.2015 00:11:17
LastWriteTimeUtc  : 02.06.2015 22:11:17
Attributes        : Archive
```

The properties and methods an object has can be inspected with the [`Get-Member`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849928.aspx) cmdlet:

```
PS C:> $f | Get-Member

   TypeName: System.IO.FileInfo

Name                      MemberType     Definition
----                      ----------     ----------
Mode                      CodeProperty   System.String Mode{get=Mode;}
AppendText                Method         System.IO.StreamWriter Append...
CopyTo                    Method         System.IO.FileInfo CopyTo(str...
Create                    Method         System.IO.FileStream Create()
CreateObjRef              Method         System.Runtime.Remoting.ObjRe...
...
PSIsContainer             NoteProperty   System.Boolean PSIsContainer=...
PSParentPath              NoteProperty   System.String PSParentPath=Mi...
PSPath                    NoteProperty   System.String PSPath=Microsof...
PSProvider                NoteProperty   System.Management.Automation....
Attributes                Property       System.IO.FileAttributes Attr...
CreationTime              Property       datetime CreationTime {get;set;}
CreationTimeUtc           Property       datetime CreationTimeUtc {get...
Directory                 Property       System.IO.DirectoryInfo Direc...
...
BaseName                  ScriptProperty System.Object BaseName {get=i...
VersionInfo               ScriptProperty System.Object VersionInfo {ge...
```

In your example, `$latest.Name` returns the value of the property `Name`, which, as you can see above, is just the filename without the path. Thus `$fileName` would contain just the value `filename`, not `c:\users\pb\desktop\source\filename`.